# Ezekiel's vision of the living creatures and the wheels

Tags: ezekiel, angels

Why are the living creatures and the wheel within the wheel of Ezekiel 1:4-24 lifted up off the earth? See especially Ezekiel 1:19-21.

> 1:19 When the living beings moved, the wheels beside them moved; when the living beings rose up from the ground, the wheels rose up too. 1:20 Wherever the spirit would go, they would go, and the wheels would rise up beside them because the spirit of the living being was in the wheel. 1:21 When the living beings moved, the wheels moved, and when they stopped moving, the wheels stopped. When they rose up from the ground, the wheels rose up from the ground; the wheels rose up beside them because the spirit of the living being was in the wheel. ([NET](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Ezekiel+1:19))

Comment: This question could be improved by providing Scriptural references.

Answer (score 2):

It is believed that these living creatures and the wheels make up the throne of God.

In chapter 1 of Ezekiel, we see that:

> 26 And above the firmament that was over their heads was the likeness
>   of a throne, as the appearance of a sapphire stone: and upon the
>   likeness of the throne was the likeness as the appearance of a man
>   above upon it. 27 And I saw as the colour of amber, as the appearance
>   of fire round about within it, from the appearance of his loins even
>   upward, and from the appearance of his loins even downward, I saw as
>   it were the appearance of fire, and it had brightness round about. 28
>   As the appearance of the bow that is in the cloud in the day of rain,
>   so was the appearance of the brightness round about. This was the
>   appearance of the likeness of the glory of the LORD. And when I saw
>   it, I fell upon my face, and I heard a voice of one that spake.

These verses indicate that above the wheels and creatures (or beings), is the "glory of YHWH".

Ezekiel 10 reveals:

> Ezekiel 10:19: And the cherubims lifted up their wings, and mounted up
>   from the earth in my sight: when they went out, the wheels also were
>   beside them, and every one stood at the door of the east gate of the
>   LORD’S house; and the glory of the God of Israel was over them above.

They are transporting "the glory of the Lord" the they are lifted up based on where God desires for them to travel.

Answer (score 0):

The creatures are jets. The wheel inside a wheel is the tire and the wheel inside a wheel is a rim and the eyes that were all around the rims are lug nuts. When they lifted up the wheels lifted up against them. You have to think Ezekiel was written around 565 and 535 BC.

If he would've seen a car coming down a dirt road the only way he could describe it as some kind of creature.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.